# bitmap save a generic error occurred in gdi+

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

I have problem with saving this `Bitmap`. I tried the `ImageFormat.Jpg` format but with the same result. I am sure of that path is true.

```
        string filePathTemp = Server.MapPath("..") + @"\ProductImages\Temp\";

        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor();

        fuProductImage.SaveAs(filePathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);

        Bitmap orgImage = new Bitmap(filePathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);

        Bitmap resizedLargeImage = imageProcessor.Resize(orgImage, 350, 350);

        resizedLargeImage.Save(filePathLarge, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

My error is famous save a generic error occurred in gdi+. Do you have any suggestoin?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `orgImage` variable come from? How is it initialized/constructed? Please show your code.

Comment: What error are you getting? Does "My error is famous" mean that we should go google it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                ImageConverter img_converter = new ImageConverter();
                System.Drawing.Image img = imageProcessor.Resize(orgImage, width, height);

                byte[] bytes = (byte[])img_converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + fileName, bytes);
```